# F#: Sequence of SQLiteCommand not working, but single SQLiteCommand works. No errors given

Tags: sqlite, f#, sequence

I'm creating an application that creates a SQLite db by code.

It works fine, i can create a Db, Tables and add attributes to the tables.

I was trying to optimize it a bit, by taking a sequence of queries, and then execute them all together.

I've noticed that the sequence of SQLiteCommand won't work, but the single SQLiteCommand works fine.

Here is the snippet of code my code that works with the sequence:

```
// Insert attribute
let rec querySeq container = seq {
    Console.WriteLine("More attributes? S/N")
    match Console.ReadLine() with 
        | "S" | "s" -> 
            Console.WriteLine("Name?")
            let atrName = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Type?: \n-int\n-string\n-datetime")
            let atrType = Console.ReadLine()
            match atrType with
                | "int" ->      
                    yield sprintf "alter table "+ TableName + " add "+atrName+" integer"
                    yield! querySeq container
                | "string" ->   
                    yield sprintf "alter table "+ TableName + " add "+atrName+" varchar(20)"
                    yield! querySeq container
                | "datetime" -> 
                    yield sprintf "alter table "+ TableName + " add "+atrName+" datetime"
                    yield! querySeq container
                | _ -> failwith "Error in attribute choice"
        | "N" | "n" -> sprintf "Done" |> ignore
        | _ -> failwith("Only S/N")
}

let container = querySeq Seq.empty

printfn "%A" (Seq.toList container)
//Execute multiple
let commands = Seq.map(fun elem -> new SQLiteCommand(elem, connection) ) container
Seq.map(fun (elem : SQLiteCommand) -> elem.ExecuteNonQuery() ) commands |> ignore


 //Try single query
let structureSql = sprintf "alter table "+ TableName + " add t1 varchar(20)"
Console.WriteLine(structureSql)
 //Execute query
let structureCommand = new SQLiteCommand(structureSql, connection)
structureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore 

connection.Close()
```

I don't really get why it's not working with a sequence of commands, but the single one works. 
I mean, i won't even return any error, so i don't really understand where the problem is.

Could it be a connection problem? Do i need to open multiple connections to the same db?

Comment: You should remove every single `ignore`. That's a footgun that will hide partial application of functions, for example, which would cause exactly this.

Comment: @glennsl i've removed the ignores, but i'm still having the same issue. 
Furthermore, why sould'nt i use the ignore? Are'nt they made to ignore the "return" of an operation?

Comment: If you add a parameter to a function that's being called with `ignore` then you end up ignoring the partially applied function, so the function isn't run at all. I've seen this cause bugs. When using `ignore` it's best to add the type parameter to be more explicit about what you're ignoring, e.g. `ignore<int>`, in which case adding a parameter causes a compile error at the call site.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't knew about it

Comment: Ah, forgot that you can give it a type parameter in F#. Anyway, you're not using the sequence, just throwing it away. Sequences are lazy, so it won't do anything unless you iterate through it somehow. That's pretty much why the concept exists. Use `Seq.fold` or `Seq.toList` to do _something_ to it, then things should start happening.

Comment: I just threw away the code with the sequence and made it work otherway. 
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `Seq.map` is lazy so none of the sequence values are being evaluated. You could use `Seq.iter`, which forces an action all all items:

```
container
|> Seq.iter(fun elem ->
    (new SQLiteCommand(elem, connection)).ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore<int>)
```

Or `for`/`do` syntax:

```
for elem in container do
    (new SQLiteCommand(elem, connection)).ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore<int>
```